# Design sql tables with list of foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create an application for rotating pairs in a team every day. I need to store this in the database. Requirments are:

- A team should be assigned to one ore more members.
- Each team can have multiple tabs and different members allocate in them.(If team consist of 4 members for the particular tab only 3 should be part of it)
- Each tab will have a pair of members or list of pairs per day stored.

I have ended up designing something like the example below:

```sql
create table if not exists team (
    id serial not null primary key,
    name text not null
);

create table if not exists member (
    id serial not null primary key,
    team_id integer references team(id),
    nickname text
);

create table if not exists team_tab (
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    team_id integer references team(id) on delete cascade,
    name text not null,
    member_ids integer[],
);

create table if not exists team_tab_pairs (
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    team_tab_id integer not null references team_tab(id) on delete cascade,
    tab_date date not null,
    pair_ids integer[][],
);
```

I need an advice and suggestions how could I achieve this without having a list of references ids stored in the 2 tables below.

Comment: You have the right idea. Storing multiple values in a single column goes against normalization. In fact 1NF explicitly forbids it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra table to design an M:N relationship. This is the case, for example, between "team tab" and "member". In addition to both *main* entities:

```
create table member (
    id serial not null primary key,
    team_id integer references team(id),
    nickname text
);

create table team_tab (
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    team_id integer references team(id) on delete cascade,
    name text not null
);
```

...you'll need to create a table to represent the M:N relationship, as in:

```
create table team_tab_member (
  team_tab_id bigint not null,
  member_id int not null,
  primary key (team_tab_id, member_id) -- optional depending on the model
);
```

Comment: What about the second table tab_pairs which needs to host the pairs for each day ?